# Rails not adding model field to insert query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, null

I've added a column to a db in rails via a migration, and updated new.html.erb to add the field to the form.

The correct data is in the request params, but the insert query that is generated has a null for the column every time.

Here are the request params:

```
{"commit"=>"Create",
  "assignment"=>{"start_date"=>"08/04/2010",
  "project_id"=>"5",
  "allotment"=>"50",
  "person_id"=>"33",
  "end_date"=>"08/05/2010"},
  "authenticity_token"=>"8f157a2a220caf716607162ce9557ab6505aab1a"}
```

and here is the resulting error with query showing the null column:

```
Mysql::Error: Column 'end_date' cannot be null: 
INSERT INTO `assignments` (`start_date`, `created_at`, `project_id`, `updated_at`, `allotment`, `person_id`, `end_date`)
VALUES('2010-08-04', '2010-08-04 03:36:21', 5, '2010-08-04 03:36:21', 50, 33, NULL)
```

Here's the migration in question:

```
class ChangeDates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :assignments, :end_date, :date, :null => false
    rename_column :assignments, :date, :start_date
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :assignments, :end_date
    rename_column :assignments, :start_date, :date
  end
end
```

I can't figure out what went wrong.  I've rolled back and migrated the change a couple of times with no luck.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Please post the code from your migration.

Comment: Are you using :attr_accessible or anything?
could you post your model of Assignment

Comment: Actually I was using at attr_accessor.  Commenting it out solved the problem!  Thanks so much.  Do you why that is the case?  If you post an answer I will mark it as the solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer you question about attr_accessor, scope will call the accessors method before the class method, so were saving the value to the accessor, but when the save was called it was returning the method call. I hope this clarifies it by example: http://codepad.org/gAppUMc4

I've done the same thing several times. Its super frustrating.

Comment: Very interesting, and I must say not all that intuitive (at least to me).  Good thing there are folks like you around to help me out :)  Thanks.

Comment: the beauty of Ruby is also the details. enjoy creating magic.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, try restarting your webserver. Rails might be caching the column names.

What version of Rails and what webserver are you running?

Comment: Thanks, I did try that.  Using Rails 2.2.2 with Mongrel 1.1.5